# Getting a substatus 0 on 403 IIS error - after login with cookie

Tags: mod-security, iis-10, trace

[Not a server admin]
I have just moved an existing site to a new server 2019, running IIS 10.

The site is an old .asp website, using a login with cookies.
When trying to login (and successfully authenticated on server side) - I get forwarded to a 403 error page. When I delete my cookie via the browser - I can see the site content and do not see the error anymore (and of course i cant see the protected area)

Having setup Failed Request Tracing, it seems the sub-status is 0. This image below seems to be the relevant event from the Trace file, but does not seem to give me much info.

Is there a security settings somewhere that needs to be configured for cookie using?
If further details are needed, happy to try provide.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: FRT has explained a lot. Such errors were caused by ModSecurity, which isn't an IIS built-in component. You need to verify its configuration and talk to whoever install it on the server.

Comment: @LexLi - Thank you.